# How do I get IntelliJ 14 to pick up Typescript tsconfig.json file?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, intellij-14, typescript1.7

How do I configure IntelliJ 14 to pick up a Typescript tsconfig.json file?

The bundled Typescript compiler is v1.4 which doesn't support tsconfig.json files, according to:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Therefore in File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript > Compiler version, I've chosen the "Custom directory" option and set it to:

```
$HOME_DIR\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib
```

Which is my install of Typescript version 1.7.5 which does support tsconfig.json files.

This however doesn't pick up the tsconfig.json file when using the "Compile all project files" option in the TypeScript Compiler pane.

I've also tried setting a command line option of:

```
-p $MY_PROJ\src\main\web
```

which contains the tsconfig.json file.  This also doesn't work and the TypeScript compiler produces an error of:

```
Error: Cannot start compiler process: Error: Cannot read tsconfig
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as i know there's no way of specifying the location of the `tsconfig.json`, it finds it automatically. Two things: 1. Make sure that your `tsconfig.json` file is located in the Scope you chose in the TypeScript settings, 2. Are you "stuck" with IntelliJ 14? because version 15 is bundled with ts version 1.7.3

Comment: Hi Nitzan - yes am "stuck" with 14 - JetBrains moved to subscription pricing just after I bought 14!   I did notice this says tsconfig.xml should be in the root of the development project - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json.  Tried the -p option to specify that but no luck in getting that working.

Comment: Have you tried [Transpiling TypeScript using a File Watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/transpiling-typescript-to-javascript.html#d226213e561) instead of the TypeScript Compiler they have?  With that you can pass what ever you want to the `tsc` program

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `webpack` to transpile down to JS but wanted to continue using IntelliJ auto-complete and warnings for typescript.

I re-located my `tsconfig.json` file to a sub-directory `buildPipeline/config/tsconfig.json` and IntelliJ was not picking up some of my `tsc` settings like `"experimentalDecorators": true`

Seems like I'm having success specifying the location of the config file by using `--p path/to/tsconfig.json` in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript

[image: TypeScript service options]

Hopefully that works for some others?

Comment: This works for me.   I have a main `tsconfig.json` then a second `tsconfig.intellij.json` that uses `"extends": "./tsconfig.json",` then overrides some intellij-specific settings.  This seems like a clean way to pull it in.